# Would services or whole operating systems written in pure Python/Java be safer?

Tags: windows, linux, java, operating-systems, python

Many Windows and Linux services are written in C and/or C++. Due to that fact, they can be exploited in several ways due to the lack of memory security (buffer overflow, etc.).

Are services written in Python/Java safer than those written in C/C++?
Would a whole operating system based on Java/Python (if thats even possible) be safer than the current operating system alternatives?

Comment: It would reduce (not eliminate, since _something_ has to manage memory directly) one vector (of many), at the cost of a large performance hit -- and the hit isn't the fact that the languages are scripting languages, the hit is that one-size-fits-all memory management is extremely wasteful.  It's not a tradeoff that most people will make voluntarily.

Comment: If the code is written properly, one language isn't more secure than any other. This might help, but assuming the people writing these tools are competent, there isn't too much to be gained.

Comment: @Pheric That presupposes that there's some level of competence where people don't make errors in programming.  No such human exists or ever will.  The easier you make programming errors to happen, the more likely they will, even with the most experienced developer in the world.

Comment: @Ghedipunk This is essentially the same argument that was made when "high level" languages like C or COBOL were introduced over assembly language.  Nobody is forcing anyone to use interpreted languages, it's all come about from choice.

Comment: it's possible yes, at least on the userland level. The only interface that needs to be written in assembly is the syscall() function, everything else can be written in higher level languages. Writing a large part of the kernel on high level language is also theoretically possible if you can somehow figure out how to run the interpreter in kernel mode (which will be tricky but is doable), but there are many parts that will still have to be written in assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unsure for Java, but the standard Python implementation is called C-Python and is written in C language. So (if it was even possible) an OS written in Python would ultimately be built using C.

Moreover, when we think of programming languages, most are targetted at writing applications, not OS and programmers rely on the language implementation to interact with the system. The 2 major exception that I can think of are:

- the assembly language**s**: they allow to write directly machine instructions and can easily access the hardware - simply you must rewrite everything if you use a processor having a different instruction set ...
- the C language that can easily and with no external library access memory mapped hardware registers, and (provided you use it in real mode) can access the full system memory - C++ can also be used at same level. It was invented by Kernighan and Ritchie to build the first Unix OS, and first C versions really looked closer to a macro assembly language, than to a high level language.

On the other side, Java and Python are not intended to access memory at physical well known addresses and programmers use system libraries (often written in C) to interact with the OS.

Finally the C language has a poor reputation, because it often bites beginners or non cautious programmers because a program with no error or warning can still contains a lot serious mistakes and its power of accessing any memory address allow to easily use wrong ones. And writing a correct and feature rich program is usually much longer in C than in Python or Java.

What follow is just my opinion, only guided by ~40 years of programming in different languages: what makes the security of a program is not its language but the proficiency of the programmer and above all **the respect of best practices**. Among which:

- tests written against expected and pathological use cases (the program must behave sanely when given correct input, and just protect itself and the system when given garbage)
- extensive peer review - a fellow will point suspect code that you have written a bit too quickly because you were focusing on another point, much better than you would do
- use well established patterns (those will depend on the used language and frameworks) instead of re-inventing oval wheels
- only write code easy to read and understand, and add comments for the rationale and principes for low level optimizations

This indeed adds a noticeable overhead. But robust code comes at a price. And this is indeed a real reason to use Java or Python when C is not required, because you will use less lines of code, and they will be easier to read for peer reviewers. So a robust application program written is Python or Java will be cheaper than the same in C. But I really think that trying to use Java or Python for the low level OS parts is just non sense.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java or Python instead of C or C++ does indeed (almost) completely remove the risk of buffer overflows and similar. That does not automatically make such services safe or even safer - there are whole classes of vulnerabilities (check out [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)) completely unrelated to memory safety.

So would writing an OS in Python of Java be a good idea? It's not obvious how that would even work. The OS must perform direct memory management, and you can't really do that in such a high level language. Besides, there would be performance issues. A much more viable approach would be to write your OS in a low level language that is memory safe, like Rust.

But at the end of the day, if you hire a lazy web developer like me, I'll just concatenate untrusted data straight into SQL queries anyways. And all the memory safety in the world is not going to help against that.

Answer (score 1):

Memory safety is very common source of vulnerabilities and completely avoidable. Clearly it should go. However, there are many other ways to make software unsafe that memory-safety does not directly address.

[100% Pure Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/100percentpurejavacookbook-4-1-1-150165.pdf) was a Sun trademark and marketing campaign. It required applications to be unusably platform independent. Clearly there is a need for at some point interacting with the underlying system, though the interface can be very small. Within the JDK there have been very occasional vulnerabilities when Java code has been using a backdoor that caused memory-/type-safety violations (although most claims are misreporting different vulnerabilities). In at least one case, the JVM itself has been capable of miscalculating arrays bounds checking in particular configurations.

When security is introduced it is usually to facilitate doing something that would be unthinkable without it. Typical examples of Java operating system efforts have tried to do without process isolation, which is obviously a crushingly bad idea. One of the reasons for this is that Java's dynamic nature leads to high overheads. Another case is the Java 2 Security Model (for mobile code). If you are using that attempt, or earlier attempts, to allow global state for anything then you are going to come a gutser.

There plethora of attempts at Rust-based operating systems. Rust being a non-garbage collected, memory-safe language by use of manual tracking techniques. However, gc is not itself the only performance problem. Array bounds checking is probably more important. The checking is difficult to optimise away in Java, again, because of the dynamic nature.

Exchange performance of a couple months worth of hardware development for a vastly more secure and faster to develop system? For the vast majority of cases it's a real no-brainer. How much critical processor time is spent in the OS? I want to be running application code! If it's one percent, performance complaints are that the machine is acting as literally yesterday's hardware. However, getting traction for a new OS is not easy. For a non-C/UNIX OS, practically impossible.

Also, hard real-time is tricky.

Comment: Bounds checking is easily optimized away for two patterns. One case is sequential access over an array. The other is when you access a power-of-two sized array as in `arr[i & (arr.length - 1)]`. I know the former has been done regularly for a long time now. I'm not sure how often the latter is taken advantage of in practice.